# Computed variables in ggridges

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggridges

Here is a MWE:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)

ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Species, fill=..x..)) +
geom_density_ridges_gradient()
```

My query is : can we not say `fill = Sepal.Length`?

I understand that `..x..` refers to a computed  variable `x` and the call to `geom_density_ridges_gradient` will probably not see the variable in the ggplot terminology, but at the time of the ggplot incantation we CAN refer to `Sepal.Length`, can we?

Can someone please clarify why we need to say `..x..` and not `Sepal.Length` in this case? I am not fully certain of the reasoning here.

To be more precise why does this not work:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Species, 
fill=Sepal.Length)) +  geom_density_ridges_gradient()
```

<------------I would like to rephrase my query starting here------------>

If I do :

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species)) + 
geom_density_ridges_gradient(fill = Sepal.Length)
```

geom_density_ridges_gradient will not be able to find the variable Sepal.Length and it gives an error.

So, the right incantation should be:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species)) + 
geom_density_ridges_gradient(fill = ..x..)
```

geom_density_ridges_gradient should be able to find the computed variable ..x.. , but it does NOT work. Can someone please explain why this is ?

Another query:

If I do :

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species,fill = Sepal.Length)) + 
geom_density_ridges_gradient()
```

Why does it not give me an error message saying Sepal.Length not found,
it simply ignores the fill argument and draws the output,why is this ?

What finally seems to work is this :

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Species, fill=..x..)) +
geom_density_ridges_gradient()
```

but I am not sure why is it that it works.

Basically I am confused as to where the argument corresponding to the fill should be placed.

Answer (score 0):

I think what might be going on here is that `Sepal.Length` is not a category.

With this in mind, can I assume that this is what you're after? (If not, let me know, and I'll try to answer what it is that you need.)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggridges)

ggplot(
  data = iris, 
  aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Species, fill=Species)
  ) + 
  geom_ridgeline(
    stat = "binline", 
    bins = 20, 
    draw_baseline = FALSE
  )
```

Running this code generates this chart:

[image: ggridges-chart]

However, if you wanted to group by `Sepal.Length`, as you suggest, you could add the following (from [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggridges/versions/0.5.0/topics/geom_density_ridges)):

```
ggplot(
  data = iris, 
  aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Species, fill=Species, group=Sepal.Length)
  ) + 
  geom_ridgeline(
    stat = "binline", 
    bins = 20, 
    draw_baseline = FALSE
  )
```

... Which would generate the following:

[image: ggridges-group-chart]